# Redirecting user if that user if done with that page Ionic

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, routes

I'm confused on how to redirect user while on login

Scenario:

-> After filling up login details and submitting, the user is redirected to an examination test. After Filling it up, the user will now then be redirected to the home page. When the user decides to log out, and then login back again, the user must be redirected to the home page.

I'm planning on my `auth.ts`, upon the first login, on my firebase, I will set a checker like 1's(If user is done with the test) and 0's (If user is not done with the test)

```
User
|_UID
  |_Checker:"1/0" // Either 1 or 0
```

Below is the code for the Login:

```
loginUser() {
if (!this.loginForm.valid) {
  console.log(this.loginForm.value);
} else {
  this.authData.loginUser(this.loginForm.value.email, this.loginForm.value.password)
    .then(authData => {
      //if user is done with the test
      this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
      //else
      this.navCtrl.push(TestPage);

    }, error => {
      this.loading.dismiss().then(() => {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          message: error.message,
          buttons: [
            {
              text: "Ok",
              role: 'Cancel'
            }
          ]
        });
        alert.present();
      });
    })
```

Auth.ts

```
 loginUser(newEmail: string, newPassword: string): firebase.Promise<any> {
return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(newEmail, newPassword)
   .then(newUser => {
    const x = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;

    if (x != null) {
      firebase.database().ref('/Users').child(newUser.uid).set({
        email: newEmail,
      })
    } else {
      firebase.database().ref('/Users').child(newUser.uid)
    }
  })}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do add that checker then you and just add it with a conditional

```
User._Checker ? this.navCtrl.push(HomePage) : this.navCtrl.push(TestPage);
```

This is under the assumption that the checker field is a custom field created under the user auth data. And also that the `_Checker` is a boolean

update

So if the uid checker field does not exists then you need to either create a custom field in the authdata which i am not even sure you can do or create that field in the database when the user first completes the signup process. I think this is pretty common if you want to add additional user information.

```
.then(newUser => {
const x = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;

if (x != null) {
  firebase.database().ref('/Users').child(newUser.uid).set({
    email: newEmail,
    _Checked:true // <- added
  })
} else {
  firebase.database().ref('/Users').child(newUser.uid)
}
```

Comment: UID is undefined